# Limit of $n\left(1-\sqrt{\left(1-\frac an\right)\left(1-\frac bn\right)}\right)$ as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: calculus

Find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(1-\sqrt{\left(1-\frac an\right)\left(1-\frac bn\right)}\right).$$
In the book answer is $\frac{a+b}2.$
But should not $\sqrt{\left(1-\frac an\right)\left(1-\frac bn\right)}$  converge to $1$
as both factors converge to $1?$

Comment: Yes it "should", but this does not contradict the book answer.

Comment: then answer would be 0 and not (a+b)/2

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\sqrt{\left(1-\frac an\right)\left(1-\frac bn\right)}\right)=0$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(1-\sqrt{\left(1-\frac an\right)\left(1-\frac bn\right)}\right)=\frac{a+b}2.$ 
 Please read the duplicate.

Comment: $0\cdot\infty$ [is an indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms).

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you cannot sum equivalent approximations. To answer properly, you have :

$$\sqrt{(1-a/n)(1-b/n})=(1-a/2n)(1-b/2n)+o(n^{2}) = 1-b/2n-a/2n+o(n^2).$$

Then,
$$1-\sqrt{(1-a/n)(1-b/n}) = b/2n+a/2n+o(n^2).$$

Finally, you have that :
$$n(1-\sqrt{(1-a/n)(1-b/n})) =b/2+a/2+o(n^3).$$

Hope it helps.